# Unable to call for procedure

Tags: sql, db2

When I try to call the procedure with `call insertp_detail ('P005','02','T001','CAT2')` , it will show the error :

> SQL0811N The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or
>   VALUES INTO statement is more than one row. SQLSTATE=21000

The expected result that I want with this procedure is to insert the values into purchase_detail table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertp_detail
(IN purchase_id char(4), seat_id char(2), trans_id char(4), seat_type varchar(5))
BEGIN 
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(trans_id)
               FROM purchase_detail
               GROUP BY trans_id) < 3)
    THEN INSERT into purchase_detail values(purchase_id, seat_id, trans_id, seat_type);

end if;
end
```

Comment: `(SELECT COUNT(trans_id)
               FROM purchase_detail
               GROUP BY trans_id) ` It returns multiple rows - Did you mean to add a where clause in it instead of the group by
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct.  You have a `group by` which generally returns multiple rows.  Presumably you intend to count the number of rows only for the `trans_id` provided as an argument to the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertp_detail (
    IN in_purchase_id char(4),
    IN in_seat_id char(2),
    IN in_trans_id char(4),
    IN in_seat_type varchar(5)
)
BEGIN 
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM purchase_detail
         WHERE pd.trans_id = in_trans_id
        ) < 3)
    THEN
        INSERT INTO purchase_detail
            VALUES (in_purchase_id, in_seat_id, in_trans_id, in_seat_type);
    END IF;
END;
```

Note that the parameters to the stored procedure have prefixes to distinguish them from column names.

You should also list the columns for `purchase_detail` for the `INSERT` statement.